# How to export table displayed on jsp to pdf in java strust2

Tags: java, javascript, struts2, pdf-generation, itext

This is my data display in table format. I want to show as it is in PDF without using display tag library of struts2.

```
<table border="1" align="center" style="border-color: #CCCCCC; border-width: 1px; border-style: None; width: 1320px; border-collapse: collapse;" id="tablepaging">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Leave ID</td>
            <td>FROM DATE</td>
            <td>TO DATE</td>
            <td>DAYS REQUESTED</td>
            <td>APPROVER</td>
            <td>NOTES</td>
            <td>REMARK</td>
            <td>IS PLANNED</td>
            <td>REASON</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>270</td>
            <td>12/27/12</td>
            <td>12/29/12</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Sagar</td>
            <td>s</td>
            <td>s</td>
            <td>true</td>
            <td>s</td>
            <td>
                <a href="/HRIS_Updated/cancelRequest.action;jsessionid=A2313340A50DD2DAB054714BF65AB08B?leaveId=270" id="submitinvoice;jsessionid=A2313340A50DD2DAB054714BF65AB08B_">Cancel</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/HRIS_Updated/requestHistory.action;jsessionid=A2313340A50DD2DAB054714BF65AB08B?leaveId=270" id="submitinvoice;jsessionid=A2313340A50DD2DAB054714BF65AB08B_">History</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is it be possible with javascript or jquery?

Please help me with some code I have googled it for a few days but get nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using display table on jsp would be quite easire to convert it to *pdf along with .csv,.excel and son on,Here is the sample code ;

```
<display:table id="data" name="${questions}" requestURI="" pagesize="10" export="true" >
    <display:column property="label" title="Question" sortable="true"/>
    <display:column title="Graph Analysis"> <img src="${imagePath}${reportData.clientName}/${data.label}.png"/></display:column>
    <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true" />
</display:table>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know unfortunately javascript cannot create pdf files by itself. And i haven't use struts yet. But I recommend you Displaytag library which is very easy to use :)

This is what you need particularly (**with code**) : http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/10/export.html

documentation (from beginning to end) : http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/10/displaytag.pdf

Answer (score 1):

To generate a `PDF` from an `HTML` source in Java, you can use [`iText's HTMLWorker`](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-html-to-pdf-using-itext.html) module (now deprecated, the new project is XMLWorker, but this depends on the iText version you're using).

You can emulate the table you have on JSP page in an String variable of an Action, let's say `CreatePDFAction`;

Then, from the JSP, call `CreatePDFAction` with a submit button (opening the pdf on a new page, if you want).

In Struts.xml, declare `CreatePDFAction` result as [`stream` result type](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/stream-result.html), with the appropriate `contentType` (`application/pdf`), and the desired `contentDisposition` for specifying the filename, and the behavior: download it (`attachment`) or open it in browser (`inline`).

Inside the `CreatePDFAction` action, you receive the String, instantiate a new document and a new HTMLWorker, feed it with the string containing your HTML, then extract the bytes from the resulting PDF and put it in an InputStream exposed through a getter by the action.

Comment: but how do we emulate the table in jsp to string . and thanks for the solution will google on it to know more about it

Comment: Almost everytime I've used this, the HTML was entered by the user in a WYSIWYG Editor (like CKEditor or TinyMCE), then read with javascript. In your case, you can use a Java function to recreate the table you've written in the JSP, because you know how the table looks like. Or you can generate the table from Java once, and use it for the PDF AND the JSP, instead of hardcoding it in the JSP; you could even read the table with javascript and recreate it as a String parameter to send to the Action, but that would be overkill... etc. find your way based on your needs :)

Comment: thanks a lot i retrieve the table structure using jquery and the used itext html parser and boom i generated the pdf thanks a lot buddy

Comment: @Andrea Ligios nice solution Buddy searched a lot on net trying to print screen a particular table then generate pdf but u r solution was simple and effective good work keep guiding beginners like us

Answer (score 1):

```
        Finaly i got the solution here is the code


          <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                 function Retrivetable()
                {
                var table = document.getElementById("historyTable");

                if (table) {

                  // If outerHTML property available, use it
                  if (typeof table.outerHTML == 'string') {
                    $('#settable').val(table.outerHTML)
                  // Otherwise, emualte it
                  } else {
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.appendChild(table.cloneNode(true));
                    $('#settable').val(div.innerHTML);
                  }
                }
                } 
                </script>

    <s:submit
            onclick="Retrivetable()"
            value="Export to Pdf"  action="ExportToPdf" method="ExportPDF" align="bottom"/>

       In the action class  
public String ExportPDF()
    {   
            tablestruct = "<html><head></head><body>"+tablestruct+"</body></html>";
                    //System.out.println("After concat "+tablestruct);
                    try{
                        String filePath = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/testpdf.pdf");
                        System.out.println(filePath);
                        Document document=new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
                        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filePath));
                           document.open();
                           HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
                           htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(tablestruct));
                            document.close();
                            System.out.println("Done");
                            File file = new File(filePath);
                            inputStream = new DataInputStream( new FileInputStream(file));
                      }
                      catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about struts, I used `itextpdf` in JSP. 
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/getting-started.html

Hopefuly it will help

Comment: Andrew thanks for the reply it saving the pdf on the local drive. actually i want that generated pdf should automatically downloaded or it should be display on browser