# How to solve ExceptionConverter in itextpdf-5.3.0.jar?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, itext

I am trying to create a PDF from HTML content. To do that, I am using *itextpdf-5.3.0.jar*, which is a Java-based (using Struts 2) web project. I am getting the following error, and I do not know how to solve it. Please help me.

```
<%@page import="com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.ArrayType"%>
<%@page import="com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.Message"%>
<%@page import="com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.util.StringArray"%>
<%@
page import="javax.servlet.*, 
javax.servlet.http.*,
java.io.*,
java.util.*,
com.itextpdf.awt.*,
com.itextpdf.text.*,com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*,com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker,
com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper,
com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker,
com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper,
com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.Tags,
com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser
,com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CSSResolver
,com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline
,com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.end.PdfWriterPipeline
,com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.AbstractImageProvider
,com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline
,com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipelineContext
,com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.LinkProvider"
%>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
alert("Welcome 2 allTest.jsp");
</script>
<%

response.setContentType("application/pdf");
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 40, 40, 30, 30);
{
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream ms=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,response.getOutputStream());

document.open();
HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);



String pdfCon = request.getParameter("pdfCon");
String [] tokens = pdfCon.split("---");

for(int i=0; i < (tokens.length); i++) {

try{
    htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(tokens[i]));

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception: "+e);
    }

    document.newPage();

}
document.close(); 
}
%>
```

And I am getting this error:

```
ExceptionConverter: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
ExceptionConverter: com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException:          com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.TableWrapper cannot 
be cast to com.itextpdf.text.Meta
```

Comment: You are doing that ON A JSP ? No.

Comment: Struts2 is not only Java based but MVC based too, so move your scriptlet code to the action.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do this is described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13729575/1654265).

Once you'll have moved all your code in a proper Action returning a Stream result type, you will eliminate the `response.getOutputStream` (you will use a ByteArrayOutputStream instead), that is one of the few things that differ between your code and mine (that works).

If the error will still be there, at least you will have (differently from Scriptlets) the ***line number*** to debug the problem or ask targeted help here.